# Next.js beta: fetching from API based on dynamic route

Tags: api, next.js, routes

I am doing my first Next.js project and I am struggling with making this component to work:

```
"use client"

import styles from './page.module.scss'
import ListFetcher from '../components/ListFetcher/ListFetcher';
import { useSearchParams }from 'next/navigation';

export default function Home() {
    const searchParams = useSearchParams();
    const category = searchParams.get('category');
    const api_link = `/api/products/category/${category}`;
  return (
    <div className={styles.page_body}>
      <article>
        <ListFetcher api_url={api_link} />
      </article>
    </div>
  )
}
```

When I run it, I get

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object
> Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an
> array instead.

Everything works if I make the api_link static and comment out

```
"use client"
    const searchParams = useSearchParams();
    const category = searchParams.get('category');
```

ListFetcher is the component where the API call happens.

What am I doing wrong? Is there an alternative how to get the routes without making this a Client Component?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Objects are not valid as a React child in the app directory of Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74981049/error-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-in-the-app-directory-of-next-js)

Comment: I tried to do it like it said in documentation - I can not get the api_url passed to the last component, anything I try just returns more errors.
I have a homepage that does exactly that, and I am not using any client/server components wrapping.

Comment: I think I will switch to normal version of Next.js - did not expect there to be so many changes with this beta version.