# Error with Next 13 async Component Data fetching

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using Nextjs 13 and this is my component:

```
"use client";

import { Carousel } from "react-responsive-carousel";
import Image from "next/image";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";
import Product from "./product";

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="searchComponent">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
        <button>
          <i className="icon-search"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <Carousel showThumbs={false}>
        <div>
          <Image
            src={"/assets/slide1.png"}
            width="0"
            height="0"
            sizes="100vw"
            style={{ width: "100%", height: "auto" }}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Image
            src={"/assets/slide1.png"}
            width="0"
            height="0"
            sizes="100vw"
            style={{ width: "100%", height: "auto" }}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Image
            src={"/assets/slide1.png"}
            width="0"
            height="0"
            sizes="100vw"
            style={{ width: "100%", height: "auto" }}
          />
        </div>
      </Carousel>
      {/* @ts-expect-error Async Server Component */}
      <Product />
    </div>
  );
}
```

and this is my Product component:

```
import React from "react";

async function getData() {
  const res = await axios
    .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
    .then((res) => {
      return res;
    });
  return res;
}

export default async function Product() {
  const name = await getData();

  return <div>1</div>;
}
```

but it's not working and I'm getting:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead error.

I also tried this code `{/* @ts-expect-error Async Server Component */}` but this problem is still persistent.

Comment: Do you put your `Product` component in a separate file? Is it located inside the **app** folder?

Comment: yes its in another separate file and its alongside of Page.js and I put it to app folder @nart

Comment: [Data Fetching Patterns](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fetching#data-fetching-patterns) sections in their docs might help

Comment: Hi @ArmanBagheri! Since you are using `"use client"`, I assume you are using the `app` directory (let me know if you are not), in which case check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74981049/error-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-in-the-app-directory-of-next-js.

Answer (score 2):

You should load data using `getServerSideProps` and pass them to the component which should be declared in a separate folder (eg. `components`) and not as an `async` function:

```
export default function Page({ productData }) {
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      ...
      <Product productData={productData}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await axios
    .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
    .then((res) => {
      return res;
    });

  return {
    props: {
      productData: res,
    },
  };
}
```

Product component:

```
export default function Product({ productData }) {
    return <div>1</div>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. its worked :)